# Package.xml to retrieve all flows is not retrieving recently created active flows

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, package.xml

This is stumping me somewhat.

I am able to retrieve all flows using * in package.xml however any new flow I am creating as of the last few days is not being retrieved as a new flow meta file when pulling from prod into a new project.

If I include FlowDefinition in the package.xml I see in my version control the FlowDefinition for this file is being retrieved and sits in my repository as a new file to add to be tracked but nothing for the flow itself.

If I define the flow specifically in the package.xml rather than using the wildcard I am able to retrieve but this defeats the purpose of leaving the version control to manage the changes when retrieved.

Standard set-up with vscode and sfdx. .forceignore is clean and would not impact the retrieval, pulling from a sandbox into a new project I create new flow and then can retrieve. A new flow that is already in prod, if I try to pull to a new project all other flows get retrieved except the new ones however the FlowDefinition for this new flow is being picked up and tracked.

Any thoughts?

To add to this is seems any flow created after the summer release is impacted.

Comment: Might not be it, but have you checked what API version your SFDX is configured to use? Might not have any impact but I've overridden this before which means it doesn't automatically get upgraded to the latest version which can cause issue retrieving stuff in later releases.

Comment: Thanks Callum, I had the same initial thought but tested both with 58 and earlier versions. I have also created new test flows running an earlier api version post release and they do not get retrieved either.

I have boiled it down to the summer release beginning of June. All flows before this date are being pulled through using * in package.xml. All flows created after are not.

Only way I can retrieve the flows post summer release at the minute is declaring them specifically.

They do not show in workbench/other tools either but are active in prod org which is really strange.

Answer (score 1):

After speaking with Salesforce it turns out that if you have a lot of old inactive flow versions when you call flows via the wildcard in package.xml it might not retrieve all and won't throw any sort of error.

The fix was to use a destructivePackage to remove all inactive flows. Once removed I was then able to retrieve all active flows via the wildcard package.xml.